# Why is setting textContent triggering reflow?

Tags: performance, browser, requestanimationframe, reflow

I have a simple countUp/Down utility, which utilizes `requestAnimationFrame` to set the `textContent` of a specific DOM. Surprisingly every time I make the content update, the browser triggers a reflow. Is there any way to avoid this?

There is a simple demo on `requestAnimationFrame` found in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/cferdinandi/pen/MWwJqpd), using the performance tool of Chrome dev tool, you can see each callback call is followed by reflow (Layout) [image: Performance result]

To my knowledge, setting textContent shouldn't cause style recalculation. I have also tried giving the element fixed dimension, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unlike some methods](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), it doesn't trigger a reflow **synchronously**, but when the next painting will occur, the browser will still have to recalculate the layout since the `textContent` change could have changed the page's layout.

The only way to avoid a reflow at all I can think of, would be to render this text in a <canvas>.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware that not all reflow is necessary a performance hit. Playing around with canvas, it indeed did not trigger reflow, however the time it took to finish Animation Frame event did not really decrease. So I think in my use case it is safe to let reflow happen.